# SQL with 2 columns: Total Commission and Commission from top 3 users

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-5.7

I am trying to run some SQL stats on my database. I have a list of operations consisting of a date, a user ID and an amount.

What I am trying to achieve, is to have 3 columns as the result:

- The month (2020-01)
- The total of sales (xxx.xx)
- The total of sales of top 3 spenders of this month. (xxx.xx)

Here is what I wrote so far, and where I am stuck:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date_bill`, '%Y-%m') as money_month, SUM(`commission`) as 'Money' 
FROM `money` 
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT SUM(`commission`) as value, DATE_FORMAT(`date_bill`, '%Y-%m') as top3_month 
    FROM `money` 
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date_bill`, '%Y-%m') = money_month 
    GROUP BY `user_id` 
    ORDER BY VALUE DESC 
    LIMIT 3
) as Top3 
WHERE Top3.top3_month = money.money_month
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_bill`, '%Y%m') 
ORDER BY money_month DESC
```

I am stuck here now. Any tips on where to look at or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work ? What should be the expected result ? What is your current result ? Would you please answer those questions along with **sample datas**

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Almost guaranteed to be MySQL or MariaDB `:-)`

Comment: Its MariaDB. @Cid , the expected result is to have 3 columns as the result: - The month - The total of sales - The total of sales of top 3 spenders of this month.

Comment: @Tayax This doesn't tell what should be the content of the expected result.

Comment: '%Y-%m' is not the same as '%Y%m'.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of MySQL/MariaDB supports window functions, you could do this with two levels of aggregation as follows:

```
select
    mon,
    sum(com) total_commissions,
    sum(case when rn <= 3 then com end) top3_comissions
from (
    select 
        date_format(`date_bill`, '%Y-%m') mon,
        user_id,
        sum(commission) com,
        row_number() 
            over(partition by date_format(`date_bill`, '%Y-%m') order by sum(commission) desc) rn
    from money
    group by mon, user_id
) t
group by mon
order by mon
```

The inner query sums commmisions by user and month, and assigns a rank to the monthly sales of each user. The outer query aggregates again by month, and uses a conditional sum to generate the total sales of the top 3 users.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: @Tayax . . . MariaDB has supported window functions for a while.  I would recommend that you upgrade the database.

Answer (score 0):

**Quite complicated requirement.**

Join is not for this. Also, you say that **Answer** of **GMB** did not work.

What you need is

```
select left(date_bill, 7) as money_month, sum(commission) as money, money_top_3
 from money
 group by left(date_bill, 7)
 order by ... desc
```

whereas the money_top_3 can be arrived from a sub query which has sub sub query too.

```
select sum(money) from
 (select left(date_bill, 7) as money_month, user_id, sum(commission) as money 
     from money tmoney
     where money_month= left(money.date_bill, 7)
     group by user_id
     order by money desc limit 3 ) subq
```

But this too is not going to work as using date_bill of money database in where clause of sub query is allowed and **NOT** inside sub sub query.

Better you could do the second part (sub query with another sub) as a temporary table and then run the first query to join with temporary table.

Comment: Try creating a temporary table as mentioned and then run the main query to get your result. Post what you arrive at and I shall suggest further.